# EJS include is not a function Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

On many of my EJS pages I have the following code:

```
<%- include('elements/fbviewpagepixel.ejs') %>
```

It works perfectly fine except on this one page. On that one pages it gives me an error saying `include is not a function`. It looks like I was able to fix it by changing the code above to the following:

```
<%- include elements/fbviewpagepixel.ejs %>
```

Why does the first version work on all of my pages except this one? Why does it give me an error on this one page? What is even the difference between the two?

Comment: Pretty hard to answer if we don't know anything about both pages!

Comment: @pds42 I'm honestly not sure what other details are relevant. Trying to make sure I give a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't even know what other useful details I can provide while still keeping it a minimal example.

Comment: I just noticed, shouldn't this be `<%= include('elements/fbviewpagepixel.ejs') %>` instead of `<%- include('elements/fbviewpagepixel.ejs') %>` ?

Comment: Did EJS drop the support for this style of writing `<%- include('…') %>` in a version bump? Do you use different EJS versions? After a quick scan of the docs, this style seems to be the current one: `<%- include elements/fbviewpagepixel.ejs %>`. Are your "pages" different projects or just diffrent routes/urls?

Comment: @michelgotta No I should be using the same version throughout. Overall just super strange behavior. I'm just curious as to why it's behaving this way.

Comment: @pds42 Maybe... but if so why does it work on my other pages?

Comment: You don't happen to be passing a parameter called `include` into your template?

Comment: @robertklep No parameters called `include`

Comment: @CharlieFish not in `res.locals` either? Or does your template create/overwrite `include`? For fun, try rendering it as a variable: `include =
 <%= include %>`

Comment: Adding `include = <%= include %>` to my EJS files just prints `include = `.

Answer (score 18):

In the later versions of [EJS](http://ejs.co/) the "client" parameter key is reserved, and will therefore cause this error. Rename the key and it'll resolve your issue.

Comment: Client parameter key? Where does the question reference that at all?

Comment: It doesn't, but that's what commonly causes the issue described. Does the solution help?

Comment: Works for me. EJS has a feature where it inherits settings from express, merged into the data object that is passed to `renderFile`. If you don't want it to do this, just pass an empty object as additional parameter: `renderFile(fileName, data, {} /* don't merge options */)`

Comment: Thanks, this should be documented in the error message.

Comment: Ugh! I spent so much time pulling my hair out on this one. Thank you!

Comment: You are a genius! Or you wrote that part of EJS code yourself :)

Answer (score 4):

I think, this issus come from parameter passed in list.
I had the same issus on rendering my user:

```
res.render("profil-client.ejs", {
    client: myClient
});
```

But when I rename my parameter like this:

```
res.render("profil-client.ejs", {
    r_client: myClient
});
```

No more error. I'm not sure, but I think ejs use attribute "client" for internal usage. So I just rename my parameters...

Comment: I can confirm this, passing client is what was causing problem for me too, ejs version "ejs": "^2.6.1",

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue; I worked around it by deleting my node_modules folder and running a fresh > npm install.

Wish I could tell you exactly *why* this fixed things, but I went from having this error to things running fine afterwards.

Comment: I can tell you what happened: a different version of the EJS engine was installed which lacked supporting the include function literal. See my answer in this page.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the EJS bug mentioned in two of the other answers (an issue with parameter naming errors with a message about include function) there must be an issue with different EJS versions.

In my project setup I have the following packages:

```
"ejs": "^3.1.6",
"ejs-webpack-loader": "^2.2.2",
```

When I use `ejs` with an express server to compile templates on the fly at each user request, the syntax must be:

```
<%- include('elements/fbviewpagepixel.ejs') %>
```

When I use `ejs-webpack-loader` to pre-compile static files to be served by an Apache web server, the syntax must be:

```
<%- include elements/fbviewpagepixel.ejs %>
```

I haven't checked which EJS version is exactly used by the Webpack loader, but I reckon it must be different from v3.